# Need to hit enter twice, addition nextLine() not solving the problem

Tags: java

I have been researching this problem for a while now and I thought I found a solution, but to no avail.

I am creating a text based game, and when I ask the user to enter their choice as a number 1-4, they have to hit enter twice. I have to hit enter twice whether or not my nextInt() is followed by nextLine() (which is what most of my research has uncovered.)

```
public void askPlayer() {
    int playerLocation = player.getCurrentLocationIndex();
    enterRoom(map.getLocationAt(playerLocation));
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    if(map.hasLeftChild(playerLocation)){
    System.out.println ("Press 1 to go to " + map.getLocationAt(map.getLeftChild(playerLocation)).getName());
    }
    if(map.hasCenterChild(playerLocation)){
    System.out.println ("Press 2 to go to " + map.getLocationAt(map.getCenterChild(playerLocation)).getName());
    }
    if(map.hasRightChild(playerLocation)){
    System.out.println ("Press 3 to go to " + map.getLocationAt(map.getRightChild(playerLocation)).getName());
    }
    if(map.hasParent(playerLocation)){
        System.out.println("Press 4 to go back to " + map.getLocationAt(map.getParent(playerLocation)).getName());
    }
    int choice = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You picked " + choice);
    super.takeTurn(choice);
}'
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why you need a nextLine() after nextInt() ?? nexLine() would be expecting a user input

Comment: Do you mean you have to hit enter twice _before_ the "You picked ..." message gets printed? If so, can you provide a [mcve]?